# Problems with git after cvsimport

Tags: git

I'm currently trying to migrate our cvs repository to git so all old data is needed but I am running into some problems.

Importing works.

First make a local cvs using `cvs init` in `CVSREPOLOCAL`

Copy the `projectname` there from the old drive then

`git cvsimport -d /home/git/CVS_REPOLOCAL projectname -C projectname.git`

gitosis is also configured to allow writing to `projectname`

```
[group projectname]
members joe jim tom bart
writable = projectname
```

on the local machine:

```
git clone ssh://git@server/projectnane.git
```

change a file and do:

```
git commit -a
[master 8a3d0f7] test
1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
```

`gitk` shows my change as the new master

... but when trying to make the change available for everybody else on the project:

```
git push
Counting objects: 7, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 432 bytes, done.
Total 4 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
remote: error: 
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To ssh://git@k.....git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
```

Is there a way to keep the old imported data and still get a ssh gitosis for multiple users?

I had one running but without the cvs import so not a solution :(

Comment: Hi,<br>
<br>
Thanks for the fast response.<br> I've tried this after importing again from cvs<br>
mv projectname.git projectname <br>
git clone --bare projectname projectname.git <br>
<br>
Now I can push and pull from the local machine. <br>
<br>
Is this a good way to go?<br>
<br>

Answer (score 0):

You have three options:

1. Use one repository for the import and another, bare (without working copy) one for the central place. Push the code from the one where you imported cvs to the bare one. I'd consider this the cleanest option. I'd even argue to do the import on your workstation and not the server and to discard it once the switch is all over.
2. Detach head on the repository (`git checkout HEAD@{0}`) or check out another branch (`git checkout -b cvsimport`).
3. Actually implement the hook mentioned in the error message, but it's somewhat tricky and I don't think you'll actually need the work tree again.